# Callback from delay in Celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am using django-celery.  I need to download a large video file.  I would like to update my database when the file has finished downloading.  Is there a way to add a callback that will call django code, not another task, when the task has completed?  My ideal code would look like this...

```
from video.tasks import video_download
from video.models import Video

def my_callback(v):    
    v.status = "downloaded"
    v.save()

def download_http(request):
   v = Video.objects.latest().id #this is a string
   a = video_download.delay(v, my_callback)
```

If there is another way to update an object after a celery task has been completed, I would be interested in that also.

PS:  I tried passing in `v = Video.objects.latest()` instead of `v = Video.objects.latest().id` so I could just update the instance along the way, but celery did not like it because it was an object and not a string.  Although it didn't throw any errors, every time I called `a.ready` it returned False.

Comment: Why you don't pass the object id and perform database get and update in the end of your task?

Answer (score 1):

You can just call your Django code from the task. For example:

```
def video_download(v):
     from video.models import Video
     v = Video.objects.get(pk=v)
     do_download(v)
     v.status = "downloaded"
     v.save()
```

Comment: Hi, are you able to tell me if this means that, under the hood, celery just makes a fork of the django process for the callback to execute? (would help to know this for a related non-celery situation).

Comment: No, there's no forking per se, you start a separate Celery worker process, which listens for new tasks and when it gets one, executes it (e.g. the callback)